# Memory matching card game

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 11 images:
5 cards with red numbers (1-5) images.
5 cards with black numbers (1-5) images.
1 cover card image.

using notepad++, I want to create a VERY simple card memory game. using basic or simple JavaScript techniques.

I have tried if else statements, but am not an expert, as I am still learning JavaScript. I tried making the variables equal to multiple values, but it didn't work.

```
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Memroy card game</title>
</head>

<body>
<center>


<a href="#" onClick = "turn_card(0);"><img id="0" src ="card_cover.png" ></a>&nbsp;
<a href="#" onClick = "turn_card(1);"><img id="1" src ="card_cover.png"></a>&nbsp;
<a href="#" onClick = "turn_card(2);"><img id="2" src ="card_cover.png"></a>&nbsp;
<a href="#" onClick = "turn_card(3);"><img id="3" src ="card_cover.png"></a>&nbsp;
<a href="#" onClick = "turn_card(4);"><img id="4" src ="card_cover.png"></a>&nbsp;<br>
<a href="#" onClick = "turn_card(5);"><img id="5" src ="card_cover.png"></a>&nbsp;
<a href="#" onClick = "turn_card(6);"><img id="6" src ="card_cover.png"></a>&nbsp;
<a href="#" onClick = "turn_card(7);"><img id="7" src ="card_cover.png"></a>&nbsp;
<a href="#" onClick = "turn_card(8);"><img id="8" src ="card_cover.png"></a>&nbsp;
<a href="#" onClick = "turn_card(9);"><img id="9" src ="card_cover.png"></a>&nbsp;


<script>

 var card = new Array(10);


       card[0] = "b5.png";
       card[1] = "r1.png";
       card[2] = "b1.png";
       card[3] = "b2.png";
       card[4] = "r2.png";
       card[5] = "r3.png";
       card[6] = "r4.png";
       card[7] = "b3.png";
       card[8] = "r5.png";
       card[9] = "b4.png";

    var number = new Array(5, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4); //card number
    var ura_omote = new Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) //front and back flags
    var times = 0;      //Number of cards flipped

    var front_card_num = new Array ( 10, 10 );  //positions of flipped cards
number[5]=card[0],card[8];
number[4]=card[9], card[6];
number[3]=card[7],card[5];
number[2]=card[3],card[4];
number[1]=card[1],card[2];


 function turn_card (g) {
document.images[g].src=card[g];

}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

this is how I want the processing to go like:

(step 1): start

(step 2): is the picture "cover card"? ...
if[No] ---> [processing is over]
if[Yes]--->Change the flag on the front and back. Set the number of the card you flipped.

(step 3): is it the second picture AKA the "second card" (any picture)?...
if[No]--->[processing is over]

(step 4): if[Yes]-->Does the number of the second card match with first card's number?
if[yes]it displays as "You got it!". Then, Reset the number of turns.

if[No]--->Change the flag on the front and back to reverse the display image "Sorry". Then, Reset the number of turns.

OVER.

Comment: You could ask about one aspect of the problem, here you are asking about what?

Comment: I want to make this work. using the steps I listed above your comment